# How can I capitalize the first letter of each word?

Tags: language-agnostic, scripting

I need a script in any language to capitalize the first letter of every word in a file.

Comment: how about you help us out and tell us what file format the target file is and what platform you're running on? Excel Spreadsheet? Amstrad?

Comment: any language on any platform is fine. the more the better

Comment: This thread will be won when somebody does this using tr and/or awk.

Comment: the answers here reminds me of the famous "fizz buzz" post, where everyone suddenly felt the need to reply with programs written in all kind of bizarre languages that solves the question :)

Comment: I disagree with "the more the better" ... because on Stack Overflow, "the more the Too Broad / Needs More Focus".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python, `open('file.txt').read().title()` should suffice.

Comment: Does it work for non-ASCII characters? E.g. European accented characters?

Comment: @Craig: on regular strings it's "locale dependent," so for safety convert to unicode: unicode(open("file.txt").read(), "encoding").title()

Comment: What you say is astonishing, but a note of warning: the OP asks to capitalize the first letter without probably touching the others. title() capitalizes the first but puts lowercase all the others: "heLLO".title() returns 'Hello'.

Answer (score 12):

Using the non-standard (Gnu extension) `sed` utility from the command line:

```
sed -i '' -r 's/\b(.)/\U\1/g' file.txt
```

Get rid of the "`-i`" if you don't want it to modify the file in-place.

note that you should not use this in portable scripts

Answer (score 6):

C#:

```
string foo = "bar baz";
foo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(foo);
//foo = Bar Baz
```

Answer (score 3):

From the shell, using ruby, this works assuming your input file is called FILENAME, and it should preserve all existing file formatting - it doesn't collapse the spacing as some other solutions might:

```
cat FILENAME | ruby -n -e 'puts $_.gsub(/^[a-z]|\s+[a-z]/) { |a| a.upcase }'
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala:

```
scala> "hello world" split(" ") map(_.capitalize) mkString(" ")
res0: String = Hello World
```

or well, given that the input should be a file:

```
import scala.io.Source
Source.fromFile("filename").getLines.map(_ split(" ") map(_.capitalize) mkString(" "))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `Ruby` too, using the command line format in a terminal:

```
cat FILENAME | ruby -n -e 'puts gsub(/\b\w/, &:upcase)'
```

Or:

```
ruby -e 'puts File.read("FILENAME").gsub(/\b\w/, &:upcase)'
```

Answer (score 3):

bash:

```
$ X=(hello world)
$ echo ${X[@]^}
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple perl script that does this: (via http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2138)

```
sub ucwords {
  $str = shift;
  $str = lc($str);
  $str =~ s/\b(\w)/\u$1/g;
  return $str;
}

while (<STDIN>) {
    print ucwords $_;
}
```

Then you call it with

```
perl ucfile.pl < srcfile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

php uses ucwords($string) or ucwords('all of this will start with capitals') to do the trick.  so you can just open up a file and get the data and then use this function:

```
<?php 
$file = "test.txt"; 
$data = fopen($file, 'r');
$allData = fread($data, filesize($file));
fclose($fh);
echo ucwords($allData);
?>
```

Edit, my code got cut off.  Sorry.

Comment: Can be shortened to: <?php file_put_contents("test.txt", ucwords(file_get_contents("test.txt")));

Answer (score 1):

This is done in PHP.

```
$string = "I need a script in any language to capitalize the first letter of every word in a file."
$cap = ucwords($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

ruby:

```
irb> foo = ""; "foo bar".split.each { |x| foo += x.capitalize + " " }
=> ["foo", "bar"]

irb> foo
=> "Foo Bar "
```

Comment: that probably doesn't work because it loses all the formatting. turns any sequence of multiple spaces or tabs into just one space.

Comment: True. the gsub solution from ruby is better than this. I was just trying to be creative. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
VB.Net:

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\lowercase.txt")
Dim str As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
sr.Close()
str = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str)
Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\TitleCase.txt")
sw.Write(str)
sw.Close()
```

Comment: +1, but in vb.net you could use "StrConv" function. Example: StrConv("string goes here", VbStrConv.ProperCase)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Ruby solution, using Ruby's nice little one-line scripting helpers (automatic reading of input files etc.)

```
ruby -ni~ -e "puts $_.gsub(/\b\w+\b/) { |word| word.capitalize }" foo.txt
```

(Assuming your text is stored in a file named `foo.txt`.)

Best used with Ruby 1.9 and its awesome multi-language support if your text contains non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby:

```
str.gsub(/^[a-z]|\s+[a-z]/) { |a| a.upcase }
```

hrm, actually this is nicer:

```
str.each(' ') {|word| puts word.capitalize}
```

Comment: irb> foo = "foo bar"; foo.gsub(/\b(\w)/) { |a| a.upcase } 

=> "Foo Bar"

Answer (score 0):

perl:

```
$ perl -e '$foo = "foo bar"; $foo =~ s/\b(\w)/uc($1)/ge; print $foo;'
```

Foo Bar

Comment: just to prove that it's not perl that's ugly, I gave you this exact solution in ruby as a response to your solution. :P

Answer (score 0):

Although [it was mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880597/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word#comment687835_880597) in the comments, nobody ever posted the `awk` approach to this problem:

```
$ cat output.txt
this is my first sentence. and this is the second sentence. that one is the third.
$
$ awk '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {sub(".", substr(toupper($i), 1,1) , $i)}} {print}' output.txt 
This Is My First Sentence. And This Is The Second Sentence. That One Is The Third.
```

#### Explanation

We loop through fields and capitalize the first letter of each word. If field separator was not a space, we could define it with `-F "\t"`, `-F "_"` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

zsh solution

```
#!/bin/zsh
mystring="vb.net lOOKS very unsexy"
echo "${(C)mystring}"
Vb.Net Looks Very Unsexy
```

**Note** it does **CAP** after every non alpha character, see `VB.Net` .

Answer (score 0):

Very basic version for AMOS Basic on the Amiga — only treats spaces as word separators though. I'm sure there is a better way using PEEK and POKE, but my memory is rather rusty with anything beyond 15 years.

```
FILE$=Fsel$("*.txt")
Open In 1,FILE$
Input #1,STR$
STR$=Lower$(STR$)
L=Len($STR)
LAST$=" "
NEW$=""
For I=0 to L-1
  CUR$=MID$(STR$,I,1)
  If LAST$=" "
    NEW$=NEW$+Upper$(CUR$)
  Else
    NEW$=NEW$+$CUR$
  Endif
  LAST$=$CUR$
Next
Close 1
Print NEW$
```

I miss good old AMOS, a great language to learn with... pretty ugly though, heh.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with awk, pretending to be simpler instead of being [shorter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753227) ;)

```
$ cat > file
  thanks for all the fish
  ^D
$ awk 'function tocapital(str) {
           if(length(str) > 1)
               return toupper(substr(str, 1, 1)) substr(str,2)
           else
               return toupper(str)
       }

       {
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
               printf("%s%s", tocapital($i), OFS);
           printf ORS
       }
      ' < file
  Thanks For All The Fish
```

Answer (score 0):

If using pipes and Python:

```
$ echo "HELLO WORLD" | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().title())"
Hello World
```

For example:

```
$ lorem | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().title())"
Officia Est Omnis Quia. Nihil Et Voluptatem Dolor Blanditiis Sit Harum. Dolore Minima Suscipit Quaerat. Soluta Autem Explicabo Saepe. Recusandae Molestias Et Et Est Impedit Consequuntur. Voluptatum Architecto Enim Nostrum Ut Corrupti Nobis.
```

You can also use things like `strip()` to remove spaces, or `capitalize()`:

```
$ echo "  This iS mY USER ${USER}   " | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().strip().lower().capitalize())"
This is my user jenkins
```