# Uppercasing First Letter of Words Using SED

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

How do you replace the first letter of a word into Capital letter,
e.g.

```
Trouble me
Gold rush brides
```

into

```
Trouble Me
Gold Rush Brides
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880597/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This line should do it:

```
sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

Comment: Note: only works with GNU sed.  If you're in OSX, FreeBSD, etc. this does nothing.

Comment: Can you describe what the command is doing? The man page, for example, doesn't list this.

Comment: It's telling sed to convert the character after each word boundry to uppercase. \b is word boundry. Check out www.rexegg.com for some great tables of useful regular expression symbols.

Comment: The key here is the `\u` token, which will uppercase the next character. For a better reference see the `Escape sequences` section of [this link](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: could you give some methods that work on macosx,thanks! @ghoti

Comment: @lslboy, not an easy task in sed without GNU sed's `\u` to force case on the match on-the-fly. One could conceivably do this in a longer sed script, but a different language would let you do it more easily. For shell access and portability, I'd probably use `awk` instead. `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(".",toupper(substr($i,1,1)),$i)}}1'` might be sufficient. If you need to maintain word boundaries, then more code is required, but it's still easier in awk than in sed.

Comment: I find a easy way in macosx,you can try it,

`echo NaMe is | perl -pe 's/([a-z])/\u\1/g'`

it work for me in macosx!

Comment: @lslboy .. not quite. The task was to capitalize just the first letter of each word, and your solution capitalizes everything. the [`tr(1)`](http://manpages.debian.org/tr) command could likely do that more easily. With perl, consider instead, `perl -pe 's/\b(.)/\u\1/g'`. The `\b` identifies a word boundary. But note that this still uses `\u`, which is a Perl RE extension, not supported universally by non-perl tools like sed.

Comment: For those on macOS, you can use homebrew to easily install GNU sed which has this feature.  `brew install gnu-sed`.  Then just use `gsed` instead of `sed`.

Answer (score 37):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }}1' file
```

The output would be:

```
Trouble Me
Gold Rush Brides
```

Comment: This seems to work on busybox, whereas the sed solutions don't.

Comment: Works on both OSX and GNU.

Answer (score 25):

Use the following sed command for capitalizing the first letter of the each word.

```
echo -e "Trouble me \nGold rush brides" | sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g'
```

output

```
Trouble Me
Gold Rush Brides
```

The `-r` switch tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions. The instructions to `sed` then tell it to "***s***earch and replace" (the `s` at the beginning) the pattern `\<.` with the pattern `\U&` ***g***lobally, i.e. all instances in every line (that's the `g` modifier at the end). The pattern we're searching for is `\<.` which is looking for a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\<`) followed by [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (`.`). The replacement pattern is `\U&`, where `\U` instructs `sed` to [make the following text uppercase](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html) and `&` is [a synonym for `\0`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html), which refers to "everything that was matched". In this case, "everything that was matched" is just what the `.` matched, as word boundaries are not included in the matches (instead, they are *anchors*). What `.` matched is just one character, so this is what is upper cased.

Comment: It is so much nicer when I don't have to do `man sed` to understand answers, because the answer contains an explanation for its contents. Maybe you would consider providing an explanation for your answer?

Comment: @JonathanKomar Edited as you requested :)

Answer (score 8):

Another shorter version with sed:

```
sed -e "s/\b./\u\0/g"
```

Answer (score 5):

I had apostrophes so, working off the first solution...

```
mike@mike-laptop3:~$ echo "BEST WESTERN PLUS BOB's INN" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

Best Western Plus Bob'S Inn

```
mike@mike-laptop3:~$ echo "BEST WESTERN PLUS BOB's INN" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | sed "s/\( \|^\)\(.\)/\1\u\2/g"
```

Best Western Plus Bob's Inn

Comment: this helps as well if you have capital letters all over, but you only want the FIRST letter of each word to be capital

Answer (score 3):

I know you said sed, but for shell scripting one of the easiest and more flexible for me was using Python which is available in most systems:

```
$ echo "HELLO WORLD" | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().title())"
Hello World
```

For example:

```
$ lorem | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().title())"
Officia Est Omnis Quia. Nihil Et Voluptatem Dolor Blanditiis Sit Harum. Dolore Minima Suscipit Quaerat. Soluta Autem Explicabo Saepe. Recusandae Molestias Et Et Est Impedit Consequuntur. Voluptatum Architecto Enim Nostrum Ut Corrupti Nobis.
```

You can also use things like `strip()` to remove spaces, or `capitalize()`:

```
$ echo "  This iS mY USER ${USER}   " | python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().strip().lower().capitalize())"
This is my user jenkins
```

Answer (score 3):

Using bash (without sed, so a little off topic):

```
msg="this is a message"
for word in $msg
do
   echo -n ${word^} ""
done

This Is A Message
```

Comment: N.B. This requires a Bash version 4 or later. `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to check.

Answer (score 2):

Using **sed** with **tr**:

```
name="athens"
echo $name | sed -r "s/^[[:alpha:]]/$(echo ${name:0:1} | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]])/"
```

Comment: Nice solution!  (Use `-E` instead of `-r` on MacOS.)  I'm using this from a Makefile (bmake) and the command I used is slightly different: `CPP_STYLE_NS!=bash -c 'export CLASS_NAME="${CLASS_NAME}"; echo $${CLASS_NAME} | sed -E "s/^./$$(tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< $${CLASS_NAME:0:1})/g"'` (Massage a given name string.)

Answer (score 2):

Capitalize the first letter of each word (first lowercase everything, then uppercase the first letter).

```
echo "tugann sí spreagadh" | sed -E 's/.*/\L&/g' | sed -E 's/(\b.)/\U\1/g'
> Tugann Sí Spreagadh
```

Answer (score 1):

Proposed `sed` solutions until now will only work if the original text is in lowercase.  Although one could use `tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'` to normalize the input to lowercase, it may be convenient to have an all-in-one `sed` solution :

```
sed 's/\w\+/\L\u&/g'
```

This will match words (`\w` means word character, and `\+` at least one and until the next non-word character), and lowercase until the end (`\L`) *but* uppercase the next (i.e. first) character (`\u`) on each (`g`) matched expression (`&`).

[[Credits](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7608/convert-a-string-to-title-case)]

Answer (score 0):

Late post, but using `ex` (or `vi`) is POSIX (like the `awk` suggestion above) so it should work on any system that ships a proper "vi" implementation.  FWIW, Busybox does not make the grade here.

[POSIX `sed` only supports BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) and I personally do not advocate relying on GNU extensions if you have a choice.

However, [POSIX `ex`/`vi` supports a few ERE features](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_58), including the word boundary `<` and the `\U` switch.  If your platform does not have a compliant `ex`/`vi` then you have bigger problems than EREs, IMO.

As a bonus, a `wq!` will optionally perform an "in-place" edit.

```
cat <<EOF > casing.txt
Trouble me
Gold rush brides
EOF
```

```
ex -s casing.txt <<'EOF'
%s/\<./\U&/g
%p
wq!
EOF
```