# Can I use awk to convert all the lower-case letters into upper-case?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file mixed with lower-case letters and upper-case letters, can I use `awk` to convert all the letters in that file into upper-case?

Comment: duplicated/related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538676/uppercasing-first-letter-of-words-using-sed

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{ print toupper($0) }' <<< "your string"
```

Using a file:

```
awk '{ print toupper($0) }' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: take note, special chars will fail :
```awk '{ print toupper($0) }' <<< stéphane

Comment: @SvennD Depends on the version — doesn't work with mawk 1.3.3, but seems to work fine with GNU Awk 4.0.1 and 4.1.1.

Comment: Generally `gawk` should handle this fine. Other awks never really made efforts to support i18n features.

Comment: @jena do you mean that gawk will not have the issue with special characters?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Yeah, I just tested it with the row of special chars on my Czech keyboard and they were all converted properly to uppercase by `gawk`, while `mawk` (1.3.4) didn't touch any of them and printed them in original lowercase form.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `awk`, but `tr` is the better tool:

```
tr a-z A-Z < input
```

or

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:] < input
```

Comment: Note that (as of coreutils 8.23) it will fail to convert accentuated characters.

Comment: Well, `tr` is not better if I need to do it e.g. on one column of a table (while keeping the rest of the table unmodified). There are reasons for `awk` specific questions ;)

Comment: @jena Quite often the reason people ask tool specific questions is that they are unaware of the existence of other tools!

Comment: I think I build my intuition about which tool to use in a similar way. And by searching for `awk` solution for my larger `awk` script, I arrived here :) worked great :) But I also learned about a new use for `tr`, so thanks! It's just this time I was here for `awk`, and so I got triggered by "`tr` is better" :D

Comment: @jena Ah, yes, perhaps I should explicitly state that `tr` is the better tool *for this particular problem*.  `awk` is certainly more flexible!  I did not in any way intend to denigrate `awk`.  Indeed, `tr` is quite limited.

Comment: No worries, you did answer the OP, sorry about jumping up like that :D

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ echo mix23xsS | awk '{ print toupper($0) }'
MIX23XSS
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
< yourMIXEDCASEfile.txt awk '{print toupper($0)}' > yourUPPERCASEfile.txt
```

Comment: Ok... how about `awk '{print toupper($0)}' yourMIXEDCASEfile.txt > yourUPPERCASEfile.txt`

Comment: it was not i to downvote your post, but the second solution, without cat, is way better

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this thread explains:
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/24320-converting-file-names-upper-case.html
(Ok, it's about filenames, but the same principle applies to files)

Answer (score -1):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -ne 'print uc()' file
```

- `-n` loop around input file, do not automatically print line
- `-e` execute the perl code in quotes
- `uc()` = uppercase

To print all lowercase:

```
perl -ne 'print lc()' file
```