# Capitalize words in a bash variable using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am totally new on shell scripting (actually three days only :) ) so don't shoot me .. !!

In my script I have a code that looks like that:

```
string="this-is-my-string"
```

and I like to modify the content of the variable, in order to become like that:

```
string="This Is My String"
```

I don't look for the regex that modify the original string into the modified version. I already have find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538676/uppercasing-first-letter-of-words-using-sed).

What I am looking for, is how to modify the text inside the variable using the `sed` command. To be honest, I don't really know if that possible with `sed`. In case that modification it is not possible to be done with `sed` is there any other method to achieve the same result ?

Comment: You can always do `your_var=$(command with $your_var)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string=$(sed 's/^./\u&/; s/-\(.\)/ \u\1/g' <<< $string)
```

**Example:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat File
#!/bin/bash

string="this-is-my-string"
string=$(sed 's/^./\u&/; s/-\(.\)/ \u\1/g' <<< $string)    
echo "$string"

AMD$ ./File
This Is My String
```

`s/^./\u&/` => Capitalize the first character `\u` for uppercase. `&` => the matched pattern.

`s/-\(.\)/ \u\1/g` => substitute `- followed by character` to `space followed by uppercase of the character`. `( )` used to group pattern and `\1` => first group, in this case only 1 such group is present.

Comment: I get this error : ./extract.v1.sh: 50: ./extract.v1.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected. I think that comes from the `<<<`. What's that ?

Comment: I changed the `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` and worked. Thanks ... !!

Comment: I get this output on my Macbook:  `uthis uis umy ustring`.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah that's possible, try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="this-is-my-string"
string=$(echo ${string} | sed 's/\-/ /g')
echo ${string}
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted you but i think the person who did may have done so because OP also changes the first letters to capitals. Just a heads up :)

Comment: Yeah didn't pay any attention to that as the OP stated he already solved that problem and said he was just after a solution to use sed for manipulating variables.

Comment: Using echo has gotchas - e.g. quotes will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

A pure Bash (Bash≥4) solution with [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ string='this-is-my-string'
$ IFS=- read -r -a ary <<< "$string"
$ string="${ary[@]^}"
$ echo "$string"
This Is My String
```

Comment: Which part capitalises the beginning of the words ?

Comment: @Jidder: it's the single caret (`^`) that appears in `${ary[@]^}`: this will expand all the fields of the array `ary` with the first character converted to uppercase.

Comment: Ahh right, did not know you could do that,thanks! Are there any other transformations that can be done in a similar way ?

Comment: @Jidder: Apart from upper/lower-casing first character or whole string, replacements, substrings (prefix/suffix), there are no other transformations.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested this is quite simple in `Python`, from the `interpreter`:

```
>>> string = "this-is-my-string"
>>> string = ' '.join([ s.capitalize() for s in  string.split('-')])                                                                                                          
>>> print string
This Is My String
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this too

```
 echo '"this-is-my-string"'|sed 's/-/ /g;s/\([^"]\)\(\S*\s*\)/\u\1\2/g'
```

or

```
echo "$string"|sed 's/-/ /g;s/\([^"]\)\(\S*\s*\)/\u\1\2/g'
```

the `\S` is a metacharacter that matches any character that is not a space/whitespace
and `\s` matches any characters that is a space

Answer (score 1):

Here is an  `awk` solution:

```
echo "this-is-my-string" | awk -F- '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}1'
This Is My String
```

```
string='this-is-my-string'
string=$(awk -F- '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}1' <<< "$string")
echo "$string"
This Is My String
```

---

Here is another `awk`

```
echo "this-is-my-string" | awk -F- '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/./,toupper(substr($i,1,1)),$i)}1'
This Is My String
```