# Capitalise the first letter of the commit message

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I'm not a perl user so I'm unsure of how to write a git commit-msg hook script to capitalise the first letter of the message for each commit so that

```
initial commit
```

becomes

```
Initial commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a [`commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) is generaly used only to *validate* a commit message, not change it.
You can still try and change the content of the temporary file passed as parameter to that hook.

Second, that hook can be a simple bash sed command:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -ie "1 s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/" $1
```

(see "[Uppercasing First Letter of Words Using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538818/6309)")

Comment: I went to the git-scm.com link and it says that `This hook generally isn’t useful for normal commits; rather, it’s good for commits where the default message is auto-generated, such as templated commit messages, merge commits, squashed commits, and amended commits.` How can I use this feature for normal user entered commit message?

Comment: @nick-s it also says, just after the passage you mention "You may use it in conjunction with a commit template to programmatically insert information." That is *precisely* what my answer does.

Comment: @nick-s I see what you mean: the default message is not the one written by the user. But I don't think the commit-msg hook allows to change the content of the message, only to validate it. You can try the same sed command I mention with a commit-msg hook. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: So if I were to add a custom message using `-m`, it can't be changed/manipulated programmatically by git hook?

Comment: @nick-s if the commit-msg does not change the content after your sed command (or an even simpler command just for testing: echo test>$1), then no. Did you test a simple content modification done with that hook?

Comment: It wasn't working on the repo I wanted to set it up in. But it works on the other repo. So accepting the answer.