# How to convert fully qualified class name into title case using a bash script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I need to convert something like this

```
androidx.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
```

To this

```
Androidx.Arch.Core.Executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
```

I know that `sed` could likely help me but I'm not proficient enough to build the correct command.

Comment: What was your research on that? I found similar: [Capitalize words using `sed` or `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538676/uppercasing-first-letter-of-words-using-sed) Could adjust for `.` boundaries, idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⚠️ Not tested!

```
# Converts to upper-case:
# first word-letter at start or following a period 
$ sed -e 's/^.|\.\w+/\u&/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

This uses common regular expression matcher:

- `^` start of line, followed by any single character `.` (i.e. the initial letter at start)
- `|` as boolean OR
- `\.` for the period, followed by `\w+` for one or many word-characters (letters)

but also some specials like:

- back-reference `&` (full match pattern), where following is applied to:
- transformation from  *GNU extensions* `\u` (uppercase the next character of match), that may not work on MacOS.

#### Use sed's GNU extensions on MacOS

On MacOS  (BSD sed) you can use `gsed` which must be installed, e.g. using *homebrew*:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581564

Alternatively you may achieve same (regex-uppercase transformation) by using *Perl*: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615804

Comment: Done, used `perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/^.|\../\U$&/g'`. Will mark your solution since helped me to get to the correct regex. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Pure Bash solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

class=androidx.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor

IFS=.

# Split Fully Qualified class path elements into array using dot delimiter
read -r -a class_array <<<"$class"

# Join the class_array's capitalized class path elements using the dot delimiter
printf -v title_class '%s' "${class_array[*]^}"

# Printout the original Fully Qualified Class Name
# and its matching Title Case Class Name
printf 'FQCN: %s\nTCCN: %s\n' "$class" "$title_class"
```

Output:

```
FQCN: androidx.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
TCCN: Androidx.Arch.Core.Executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor
```

Alternate method with function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

class2Title () {
  IFS=.
  set -- $@
  echo "${*^}"
}

class2Title net.example.bar.Foo
```

Output:

```
Net.Example.Bar.Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fully functioning `sed` statement. (tested)

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/androidx.arch.core.executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor/Androidx.Arch.Core.Executor.AppToolkitTaskExecutor/g" {} \;
```

**Note** that in the `find` I left it recursively from the directory you are currently "in" ..  If you need to search a specific directory, it'll look like `find /path/to/your/dir -type ...`

Comment: Thanks @Zak. This is specific for one class name, I need a solution for a random class name.