# Bash Converting to title case without letters following a diacritic being capitalised

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file, test.txt,  in (Mac OSX bash,   UK english locale) containing three names, one of which is accented (diacritic)

test.txt

```
Ève
Eve
eve
```

I want to convert all to Title Case.

```
cat test.txt  | gsed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

yields the result

```
ÈVe
Eve
Eve
```

The issue is that the first one, ÈVe,   should be Ève

The diacritic has been followed by an incorrect capitalisation within the name.  How can I amend the pipe sequence to either prevent (preferable) or correct this issue?   For the purposes of the question, please assume no LC_* environment variables are set

Comment: What version of `gsed` do you have? Testing on a Linux system with `sed --version` giving "sed (GNU sed) 4.7", it works for me with a UTF-8 locale set, but with no LC_ variables I get "??Ve" for the first line (where the "?" characters are actually hex FF bytes). Anyway, on general principles I'd recommend replacing the second command in the `sed` argument with `s/\<[[:alpha:]]/\u&/g`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson  gsed (GNU sed) 4.9

Comment: If we `assume no LC_* environment variables are set` then how is your code supposed to know which letters are present in any given character range or character class in your locale? I guess you could explicitly list all of your target characters in the bracket expression but that seems pretty tedious and error-prone.

Comment: From your comments and the answer you posted it sounds like the example you provided in your question isn't adequate to cover your real requirements so accept an answer to the question you asked (how to upper-case the first letter of a list of words that start with a letter) and then ask a new one with a more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton  I asked how to Title Case,  not solely Upper Case.    You are right that the example could have included surnames to be more inclusive.

Comment: You asked how to Title Case a list of single words and got multiple answers that do that. You then introduced `Bob Smith` and `Bob_Smith` in comments, which weren't mentioned as possible cases in your question. Don't do that. So as to not waste the time of people trying to help you, after you get answers to a question, if you meant to ask about something else then accept an answer to this question you asked and then ask a new question with more truly representative sample input/output that covers the cases you really intended to ask about.

Answer (score 2):

Use character classes. `[a-z]` is a till z. `[[:alpha:]]` are all letters. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html

```
sed 's/^\([[:alpha:]]\)\(.*\)/\U\1\L\2/g'
```

Also note that you have to have GNU sed with unicode support and locale with UTF-8 or proper encoding.

Comment: In terms of Title Case,  adding a name eg ``` Bob Smith `` or ``` Bob_Smith ``` does not convert to Title Case using this approach?

Comment: I recommend https://regexcrossword.com/ to learn regex with fun. This https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is the most informative site. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880597/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880597/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word

Comment: Grateful for clarification as per the OP re Title Case.   The solution should be able to address this :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use perl :

```
perl -pe 's/^(\w)/\U$1/' test.txt
```

Comment: Use `\u` instead for true title casing. (Not that there's a difference for the characters that RE will match)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/./\U&/' file
Ève
Eve
Eve
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^[[:lower:]].*/\u&/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` instead and assuming you're working with an UTF-8 encoded file:

```bash
$ perl -CSD -lne 'print ucfirst' test.txt
Ève
Eve
Eve
```

[`-CSD`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D) tells perl that standard input/output/error and all opened files are using UTF-8 encoded text, and the [`ucfirst`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst) function titlecases (Not uppercase like a lot of these answers; [they can be different](https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#4)) the first character of its argument (Defaulting to `$_`, which thanks to the [`-n`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n) option is each line in turn).

If you want to lower-case everything else in the text, use `print ucfirst lc`

Comment: Look, Ma! No regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution,  I have found:

```
gawk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){ $j=toupper(substr($j,1,1)) substr($j,2) }}1' "$inputFile"
```

works on an example set

```
Ève
Eve
eve
bob smith
```

Cases where eg `bob_smith` exist are easily pre-/post-processed to suit